# Question about non isomorphic ordered sets models

Tags: first-order-logic, model-theory

Reading the book What is mathematical logic? by Crossley, in page 23 after stating a set of sentences of ordering it states a Lemma (without proof). Hopefully there is enought context...

[image]

Not sure if I fully understand what the Lemma says. It is a particular one that only applies to this structure $\mathscr N$ or it is a general fact, easy to generalize?

Even if it only applies to this particular $\mathscr N$, does it means that it is imposible for this particular language (with $P$, $E$ and logical symbols) to built any formula able to distinguish the models (being true in one model and false in other)?

I guess it only aplies to this particular case, this property of a model like $\mathscr N$ of being a "complete aziomatization" of $\Sigma$ has a name?

Thanks in advance,

EDIT: (I miss some important information in the first attempt)
The previous axioms the book talk about:
[image]
[image]
They are called {Equality} in the book.

And later on it defines another model for the same axiom set called $\mathscr B$
[image]

I hope now my main question is clearer. It is imposible to write a sentence such as it is true in $\mathscr B$ and false in $\mathscr N$?

Comment: The particular set of sentences in question are the axioms of Peano Arithmetic. In particular, Peano Arithmetic completely describes the way the natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$ work (that is what $\mathcal{N}$ is in your linked passage). By complete axiomatization, of $\mathcal{N}$, what is meant that any statement that is true in $\mathcal{N}$ is provable/a logical consequence of those statements in $\Sigma$. Another way to generalize this is to say $\text{Th}(\Sigma)=\text{Th}(\mathcal{N})$. i.e. the theory of both are the same.

Comment: But $\mathcal{N}$ is not a set of formulas. It is an structure, an interpretation, a model... What does it mean $Th(\mathcal{N})$?

Comment: You are correct that $\mathcal{N}$ is a structure under some interpretation. Its theory is the set of sentences that are true under this interpretation. Maybe a bit of a vague answer, but think of $\mathcal{N}$ as a physical universe. Then, it satisfies some rules (i.e. some physical laws). The set of all these rules is the theory of $\mathcal{N}$, denoted $\text{Th}(\mathcal{N})$. Now let's say I can somehow figure out all the rules that $\mathcal{N}$ follows just by writing down a smaller number of rules. This is $\Sigma$.

Comment: The way I think about this is to think that it would be hard to write down exactly how every object will fly when thrown. Or what trajectory it will follow. But this is part of the theory of the universe. But we can figure this out simply by appealing to Newton's laws or other physical theories which are smaller but encapsulate the idea of how the universe works.

Comment: In this particular case we are not talking about Peano Axioms (at least the whole axioms). Keep in mind the language only have two predicates symbols E (for equality) and P (for less than). The structure  $\mathcal{N}$ is just the natural numbers as a set, with identity as E, and the usual < relation for P. Later on it uses another interpretation that consists of the sets {1-1/n: n>0}{1+1/n: n>1}U{3-1/n, n>0}, identit, and the < relation for P.

Comment: The $Th(\mathcal{N})$ you explained above is like $Th(\mathcal{N}):=\{\varphi: \mathcal{N}\models\varphi\}$?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is impossible to write a formula in first order logic with just $<$ to distinguish $B$ and $N$. Everything that's true of one is true of the other.

It may help to think of $B$ as the following isomorphic linear ordering:
$$0, 1, 2, 3, \ldots, \ldots, \infty - 2, \infty - 1, \infty, \infty + 1, \infty + 2, \ldots$$
That is:
$$\{n | n \in \mathbb{N}\} \cup \{\infty + z | z \in \mathbb{Z}\}$$

The only distinction between these orderings is that in $B$ there are two elements with infinitely many elements between them, while this is not true in $N$. However, first order logic cannot express "there are infinitely many $x$ such that...", since this would require infinitely many variables, and any formula in first order logic must be finite.

When we say $\Sigma$ axiomatizes $N$ completely, that means that any structure satisfying our axioms must be similarly "logically indistinguishable" from $N$. That is, there is no formula true of one structure and false of the other (a formula that "logically distinguishes" the two structures). In other words, all true formulas about $N$ follow from $\Sigma$.

Comment: I find it surpising. I can imagine very long sentence like with 1 milion distinct variables mixing for all and exist , that I have no idea what they could mean, but for sure I know it will not help to distinguish this clearly two diferent concret structures.

Comment: Sorry one more point, do you know where can I find a proof that this particular $\Sigma$ axiomatizes $N$ ?

Comment: From a first order perspective, any ordered set (one's that follows this axioms) are logically indistinguishable... Does it include reals with the well ordering?

Comment: The most intuitive way I've found of proving that two structures cannot be distinguished by a formula is Ehrenfeucht-Fraisse Games. Rosenstein's /Linear Orderings/ has a presentation of EF games for linear orderings.

Comment: The reals with a well ordering do not satisfy these axioms, specifically they do not satisfy (xiv), that every element except one has an immediate predecessor. Infinite elements have to be in parts that look like $\{\infty + z | z \in \mathbb{Z}\}$.